# Run delphi class from c# web service

Tags: c#, web-services, class, delphi, workflow

I have an delphi VCL app that through TMS workflow sends email with link which call web service method "Calculate" with parameters: a,b,c.

```
<a id="zavrni" href="http://localhost:49839/WebService1.asmx/Calculate?a=1&amp;b=2&amp;c=3">Calculate</a>
```

Now I am struggling getting back on delphi from web service so I can continue workflow(need to access delphi classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expose the Delphi routines through a Delphi web service which then can be called from the ASP.NET server code. This has the advantage that the Delphi binaries may be installed on the same or on a different computer, and the API is language-independent and platform agnostic. Calling DLLs directly would require the Delphi code to be present on the same machine.

To implement the Delphi Web Service you could use the Indy HTTP server component (included with Delphi), or the Indy TCP server component with a standard protocol (so you can use existing libraries on the ASP.NET side to invoke the service).

Comment: Isnt there any easyer alternitive? I saw your question about workflows. Whitch product did you choose and what are the benefits?

Comment: @skafinski I am not sure which question about workflows you mean, could you add a link?

Comment: https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/workflow.asp
Is it possible to create web service and there run Workflows?

Comment: @skafinski I do not understand your question 'which product you choose'. I never worked with TMS workflows.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about asp.net, but in c# you can use PInvoke 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx
to call non-managed libraries (like I assume Delphi VCL would be...)

Comment: Does it need to be on the same machine?

Comment: With PInvoke it runs on the same machine, the DLL can be located anywhere, but it willbe loaded in memory un runtime in the same machine